# How to import price from Bloomberg?

Tags: regex, xpath, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

From this website

https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAGB:MK

I want to extract the value for stock `AAGB:MK`.

In my Google Sheets, this is my formula.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAGB:MK","//a[@span class='priceText__0feeaba3']")
```

It fails to extract.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAGB:MK"), 100, 1), 
 "price%22%3A(.*)%2C%22priceChange")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: this worked all the while, but stopped working. any idea why?